# Error in running example application, Uncaught Error: SignalR: jQuery not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, signalr

I am new to asp.net. I am learning SignalR, going through this [`tutorial`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs). I have created everything correctly as mentioned in the tutorial. Now when I ran the **Console Application**, ERROR --> "One or more errors occurred." at `hubConnection.Start().Wait();`.(the console application is still running). Anyhow I tried even running the **Web application** which is not giving any error but the button `broadcast` doesnt do any action(I think it should). When I checked the code in **Web application**, I saw that one of the script source has green scribbles. Here is the Image.

[image]

Please explain what I am doing wrong..

**Edit**: I am using ASP.NET Development server.

**Edit2**: The errors I get in Google Chrome Console are:

```
Uncaught Error: SignalR: jQuery not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR.js file. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.min.js:10
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signalR' of undefined hubs:17
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

**Answer**: I just added reference of jQuery in my code above all the scripts and the "file not found" error is careless because it is running on server side.

***The Link has also been updated with reference to jQuery***

Comment: have you tried dragging the file from the explorer onto the aspx? the path might be incorrect

Comment: First all, your missing `.js` at the end and send make sure the path is correct. From the path in your example your file must be located in a folder at the root of the site called `signalr`.

Comment: I didnt create that path, I just copied it from the example code. as [mentioned here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs)

Comment: @James There is no folder like signalr(nor even hubs.js) in my webApplication. How to include it? (Its not even mentioned in the example) Any link will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message describes fully what the problem is:

> Uncaught Error: SignalR: jQuery not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR.js file.

You need to include jQuery.

Comment: Not the answer. Real answer is below.

Answer (score 8):

Just for anyone else who comes across this problem, I made the mistake of just copying the code from the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) and updating to the latest version of SignalR. The version had obviously changed and this needs to be updated in the script references i.e.

The jQuery src should be (depending on the version of signalR you have installed):

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js"></script>
```

The same thing would obviously apply to the standard jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks, your a champ!

Answer (score 1):

try `"signalr/hubs"` instead of `"/signalr/hubs"`

Answer (score 0):

Today, I upgraded jQuery and SignalR to 2.2.0 and jQuery could not loading although I added jQuery before SignalR.

And, I downgraded jQuery as 2.1.4 system working well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not relevant but I couldn't help, having English as my second language, you should say "put", not "putted". The verb put doesn't change in the past form. Another alternative is to say "I added". Thanks. @Thomas

Comment: @SamersSalib: Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

If the jQuery version is defined with npm with a `*`, e.g: `"jquery": "*",` in package.json and that version get's upgraded you might also see an issue very similar to this.

So downgrade the version of jQuery: `"jquery": "2.2.4",`